# Can not compile code on another computer: Pods.'projectname'.framework not loading

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, xcode9

I have the same xcode version (9.0.1) on both computers. It runs perfectly on one computer and not on the other. I literally copied the project folder and did a clean pod install. How ever I get the following errors. Does anybody have experience with this?

I get errors like:

- Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FirebaseStorageUi.UIImageView_FirebaseStorage'
- Could not build Objective-C module 'FirebaseStorageUI'

Would be great if someone can point me in the right direction.